# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error when compiling Qt application

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to compile a Qt application on osx using Qt creator. Application successfully compiles in widows. But in mac, it gives following linker errors.

```
2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anybody know a way to check what are the duplicate symbols the linker is complaining about? I used following in my .pro file but no success.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -v
```

Comment: Please, try to check Qt Creator output console tab and find what exactly 2 symbols are duplicated. This info should be there.

Comment: Thanks N1ghLight. I didn't know that there is a compiler output window in Qt creator

Comment: This is maybe that you included two times a `.pri` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting comment by N1ghtLight as an answer.

`Duplicate symbols found` error is a linker error, which says that linker has found more than one symbols with the same name. Following are some common causes for this.

- You have written a function definition in a header file (outside a
  class), which is included in two or more `cpp` files.
- You have defined a static variable twice.
- You have written a function definition twice in a cpp file.

You can find out what are the duplicate symbols by checking `Compile Output` tab in `Qt Creator`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I added duplicate headers at myproject.pro file.

```
ex) HEADERS += zzzz.h \ 
... a lot of xxxx.h \
zzzz.h (again)
```

I deleted duplicate zzzz.h and builded successfully.